# Forwarding EventHandlers

Tags: c#, interface, event-handling

I have a method registered as an EventHandler:

```
handler.Actiontriggered += LocalMethod;
```

Now I want to replace the handler with an interface. I ended up with something like this:

```
public interface IHandler
{
  event EventHandler<EventArgs> Actiontriggered;
}
```

and implemented as

```
public class SpecificHandler : IHandler
{
    ....
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Actiontriggered
    {
        add
        {
            this.handler.Actiontriggered+= value; // handler is the same as in the snippet above
        }

        remove
        {
            this.handler.Actiontriggered-= value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that I get an error that `EventHandler<EventArgs>` cannot be implicitly converted to a type specific to the handler.

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler<System.EventArgs>' to 'Handler.ActiontriggeredEventHandler'
```

As this worked in the original direct assignment: What to rewrite for this to function with the interface as well?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `handler.Actiontriggered` and `LocalMethod`? And is `SpecificHandler.handler` the same as the `handler` in your first snippet?

Comment: @RenéVogt SpecificHandler.handler is the same as the handler in the first snippet. The method is implemented as `Method(object o, EventArgs e)`. I dont have access to the implementation of the handler, but decompiling shows `public delegate void Actiontriggered(object sender, EventArgs e);`

Comment: So it should actually work, can you post the _exact_ error message (including the types it complains about)?

Comment: Added it into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ActionTriggered` event in the type of `handler` is **not** declared as

```
public class Handler
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Actiontriggered;
}
```

but as

```
public class Handler
{
    public delegate void ActionTriggered (object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event Actiontriggered Actiontriggered;
}
```

So you need to change your interface to:

```
public interface IHandler
{
     event Handler.Actiontriggered Actiontriggered;
}
```

and the implementing class accordingly:

```
public class SpecificHandler : IHandler
{
    ....
    public event Handler.Actiontriggered Actiontriggered
    {
        add
        {
            this.handler.Actiontriggered+= value; // handler is the same as in the snippet above
        }

        remove
        {
            this.handler.Actiontriggered-= value;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Although `Handler.Actiontriggered` is a delegate type with the *same signature* as an `EventHandler<EventArgs>`, they are *not the same type*, hence the compiler error.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to avoid (o_O)

Thanks for the answer and explanation

Comment: @Dawnkeeper you may avoid it by wrapping the `add`like `this.handler.Actiontriggered += (sender, e) => value(sender, e);`, but then I don't know a good way for the `remove` part...